# Azure SQL Database encryption

Tags: azure-sql-database, encryption, azure

Currently i have an azure subscription in it has a server and a database.

How could i encrypt an SQL azure table and when the encryption is done i can still insert some data on the table?

I already tried the encryption part but when i am trying to insert a data i received couples of error and i can't insert the data.

I am a newbie when it comes to azure and as a DBA

Comment: How have you encrypted the data, using column-level encryption or AlwaysEncrypted?

Comment: Please also add the error messages in the question which you got while inserting

Comment: currently i have another issue please see below :https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/239781/azure-database-encryption-error-on-web-app